# make guide_colourbar same height as plot area

Tags: r, ggplot2

Is there currently an easy way to make a colourbar legend the same height as the plot area. e.g. something like this:

```
p <-ggplot2(some_plot_needing_a_colourbar_legend)+
guide=guide_colourbar()
p <- p + theme(legend.key.height=plot.height(p))
```

At the moment I only see a way to set the height using an array of units (using the `unit()` function), including the height of the viewport, but not the height of the plot area. Also this function seems to specify height in absolute terms rather than relative. Am I missing something or is this not (at present) possible?

Comment: At the moment there is no easy way. As for the relative, you may set the height by `qplot(1:3, 1:3, colour = 1:3) + guides(colour = guide_colourbar(barheight=unit(0.5, "npc")))`

Comment: @kohske - thanks! The "npc" argument works great for my purposes. Using this I can easily scale the guide to something close to the plot area height. Should I open this (ability to set height of guide as plot height) as a feature request issue on ggplot2 Github and link to this question? Thanks again.

Comment: Of course, you can issue this on Github.

Comment: @PoGibas you realise that question was asked a full _year_ after mine. Add the duplicate tag on the other question.

Comment: I agree, but the other question has accepted answer.

Comment: Fine fair enough.